# Iterate over Variable in Jinja Template

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I would like to iterate over a variable in ansible yaml and add key and value in jinja template

variable:

```
my:
    variable:
        - name: test
          path: /etc/apt
          cert: key.crt
```

my template

```
{% for key, value in item() %}
      {{key}}: {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

ansible yaml

```
- name: test
  template:
    force: yes
    src: test.conf.j2
    dest: /tmp/test.conf"
  become: yes
  with_items:
    - "{{ my.variable }}"
```

How my yaml should look like:

```
path: /etc/apt
cert: key.crt
```

Comment: "msg": "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"}

Comment: same...
"msg": "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have three issues in your task:

1. When using a loop, may it be `loop` or all the flavour of `with_*` you access the element currently looped in with the variable [`item`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/items_lookup.html#examples), so not a function like you used in your task (`item()`)
2. You are doing a superfluous list of list in

   ```yaml
   with_items:
     - "{{ my.variable }}"
   ```

   A first step would be to do `with_items: "{{ my.variable }}"`.
   An ever better step would be to use the `loop` replacement of the `with_*` syntax [as suggested in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items)

   > We added `loop` in Ansible 2.5. It is not yet a full replacement for `with_<lookup>`, but we recommend it for most use cases.

   So you will end up with

   ```yaml
   loop: "{{ my.variable }}"
   ```
3. Then accessing properties of a dictionary in Jinja is done using the syntax

   ```
   {% for key, value in dict.items() %}
   ```

   <sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for*</sup>
   So in your case:

   ```
   {% for key, value in item.items() %}
   ```

---

All together, a working playbook demonstrating this would be:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for key, value in item.items() %}
            {{key}}: {{value}}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ my.variable }}"
      vars:
        my:
          variable:
            - name: test
              path: /etc/apt
              cert: key.crt
```

That yields the result:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'test', 'path': '/etc/apt', 'cert': 'key.crt'}) => {
    "msg": "  name: test\n  path: /etc/apt\n  cert: key.crt\n"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Now you just have to reuse this in your template and loop and you should have what you expect.